# CryptoZombies 内に記述されている at の意味が分からない

Tags: solidity

大まかに何をしているかはコメントを見れば分かるのですが、5行目に記述されている"at"についてになります。

この"at"はjavascriptのメソッドなのかweb3.jsのものなのか分かりません。ドキュメントを調べたのですが、配列の順番を指定する様な記述が書いてあり、少し違う様な気がします。
詳しく分かる方がいましたら宜しくお願いします。

```
// これがコントラクトにアクセスする方法だ：
var abi = /* abi generated by the compiler */
var ZombieFactoryContract = web3.eth.contract(abi)
var contractAddress = /* our contract address on Ethereum after deploying */
var ZombieFactory = ZombieFactoryContract.at(contractAddress)
// `ZombieFactory`はコントラクトのpublic関数とイベントにアクセスできるようになったぞ。

// 入力テキストを取得する類のイベントのリスナーだ：
$("#ourButton").click(function(e) {
  var name = $("#nameInput").val()
  // `createRandomZombie`関数を呼び出す部分だ：
  ZombieFactory.createRandomZombie(name)
})

// `NewZombie`イベントをリッスンしてUIを更新する部分だ
var event = ZombieFactory.NewZombie(function(error, result) {
  if (error) return
  generateZombie(result.zombieId, result.name, result.dna)
})

// ゾンビのdnaを取得して画像を更新する部分だ
function generateZombie(id, name, dna) {
  let dnaStr = String(dna)
  // 16桁未満の場合はDNAの先頭に0をつける部分だ
  while (dnaStr.length < 16)
    dnaStr = "0" + dnaStr

  let zombieDetails = {
    // 最初の2桁は頭の部分だ。頭部は7種類用意してあるから、%7して
    // 0から6の番号を取得したら、そこに1を足して1から7にするのだ。
    // これを基にして、"head1.png" から"head7.png"までの
    // 画像ファイルを用意する部分だ：
    headChoice: dnaStr.substring(0, 2) % 7 + 1,
    // 次の2桁は目の部分だ。11種類用意してあるぞ：
    eyeChoice: dnaStr.substring(2, 4) % 11 + 1,
    // シャツの部分は6種類用意してある：
    shirtChoice: dnaStr.substring(4, 6) % 6 + 1,
    // 最後の6桁は色の部分だ。 CSSのフィルタを使用して更新できる。
    // 360度の色相回転（hue-rotate)を使うぞ：
    skinColorChoice: parseInt(dnaStr.substring(6, 8) / 100 * 360),
    eyeColorChoice: parseInt(dnaStr.substring(8, 10) / 100 * 360),
    clothesColorChoice: parseInt(dnaStr.substring(10, 12) / 100 * 360),
    zombieName: name,
    zombieDescription: "A Level 1 CryptoZombie",
  }
  return zombieDetails
}
```

Comment: 可能であればコードの出典 (URL 等) も明記してみてください。

Comment: https://cryptozombies.io/jp/lesson/1/chapter/14

Comment: https://github.com/loomnetwork/cryptozombies-lesson-code

Comment: 上記になります。githubの方はまだ詳しく見ていませんが、solidityしか記載されていませんでした。後のレッスンの方でもしかしたら全体が記述されているかもしれませんので、もう一度見てみます。